# C# WPF Application Open Regular Windows Form First

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have a WPF application and want to launch a regular Windows Form first by default.  It will be an options panel, basically.

edit:  for clarification, I'd like the Windows Form to be the only form that opens automatically.  I'll then show the WPF form later.

I tried modifying App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="The_Name_Of_My.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="Form1.cs">
<Application.Resources>
```

I get an error: "Cannot locate resource 'form1.cs'."  Am I just spinning my wheels here and trying to do something stupid when I should be making the options panel in WPF?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're insisting on using a WinForm in a WPF application? If it's simply because you feel more comfortable creating a WinForm rather than a WPF Window, then you should have created your project in WinForms in the first place. If there's a good reason (e.g. you have a control that only works in WinForms and not in WPF), then there are several workarounds.

Comment: Definitely because I'm more comfortable with WinForm.  I am venturing out into WPF because there will be quite a bit of animation and so far I like how WPF handles animation.  WPF will be the primary part of this app.

Comment: `WPF will be the primary part of this app` then I'd say your whole app should be in WPF. Even though it might take some time to get comfortable writing code in XAML, once you're there, you'd never want to go back to WinForms, trust me.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange That sounds like the best plan.

Answer (score 3):

Just instantiate the Windows form in your WPF Form's/Viewmodels constructor and call ShowDialog:

```
namespace WpfApplication11
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var form1 = new Form1();
            form1.ShowDialog();

            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That definitely works.  I'll put this in an edit to clarify, but what I'm looking for is to open the Windows Form only.  This solution automatically opens the WPF once the Windows Form is closed.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when you close the windows form then?

Comment: @Geek The application will close.

Comment: I am confused.  You have a WPF application that when you launch a winforms form is shown - then you close that and the application closes?  What is the purpose of it being a WPF app then?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem for loading Windows_Form_Application as default.
But the answer is below...
just add a Windows_Form in your project and replace below code to MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Make WPF form unvisible
        this.AllowsTransparency = true;
        this.Background = null;
        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

        //Run windows from
        Form1 u = new Form1();
        u.Show();
        //Set close handle to form
        u.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //close WPF form if windows form being close
        this.Close();
    }
```

that's it...